# Sharepoint 2013 workflow: Setting Task Status to Complete causes other tasks to disappear

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

I have two SP2013 workflows. The first one is on an item list, which generates approval tasks in another list for three approvers. The approval task list also has a SP2013 workflow which gets triggered when the task gets modified by a custom form. The custom form sets the Task Outcome to Approved/Rejected, but does not set the Task Status nor Task Completion %.

Once the first approver approves or rejects, the task workflow completes but the rest of the tasks get canceled and deleted. The Task outcome in the item list shows rejected. Not sure what is causing this unexpected behavior. Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

I have attached the simplified workflow which outlines the issue

Stage:Item List Workflow

```
Log Starting Test Approval process to the workflow history list

Set Variable: ApproverGroup1 to G1
Set Variable: ApproverGroup2 to G2
Set Variable: ApproverGroup3 to G3

Start a task process with Variable: ApproverGroup1; Variable: ApproverGroup2; Variable: ApproverGroup3 (Task outcome to Variable: Outcome )

Log Task Outcome: [%Variable: Outcome%] to the workflow history list
```

Transition to stage

```
Go to End of Workflow
```

---

Stage:Task List Workflow

```
Log Starting Test Task Workflow... to the workflow history list

Set % Complete to 1

Set Task Status to Completed

Log Complete to the workflow history list
```

Transition to stage

```
Go to End of Workflow
```